# How to recursively remove all hyphen characters from filenames

Tags: debian

I have a lot of folders with 1 file inside that need batch renaming to remove this

**-(sample)**

so

filename-(sample).mp3

becomes

filename.mp3

Their parent folders have **(sample)** at the end also and I am able to remove **(sample)** on the folders  by running:

```
find . -name '*\(sample)*' | while read f; do mv "$f" "${f//\(sample)/}"; done
```

When I run this again for a second time it then strips (sample) from the contained filenames, (but not on the first run.)

So I'm left with

filename-.mp3

adding the Hyphen to the code I enter like so

```
'*\-(sample)*'
```

does not work.

I've tried plenty of other methods I've found online all day, nothing works, some commands aren't recognised on the server like 'rename'.

I'm trying to avoid downloading a couple thousand of these sample files to change the filenames locally which I could do.

The server is running Debian.

I don't know though, maybe leaving **-.mp3** is gonna be ok? seems a bit sloppy and weird? I've read leaving hyphen's at the start of filenames can cause issues, so possibly the same the other end?

I can follow instructions pretty well (and will always research answers to understand better first), but I'm no expert, so bare that in mind.

If anyone has any other suggestions that'd be great. I can remove anything I want from the folders/filenames except a Hyphen..

thx!

Comment: Mismatched title: title says `-` body says `-(sample`).

Comment: Consider the position of the `\`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all start from lowest (deepest) match in `find` - otherwise you may rename a parent directory and following renamings may fail as you cannot find the subdirectories and files there anymore. Second `rename` is (IMHO) the simpler tool. Third directly execute via `find`.

```
find -depth -name '*-(sample)*' -exec rename --nopath 's:-\(sample\)::' '{}' +
```

If you want to test first, use `-n` as option for `rename` - it will do a dry-run and show changes. The `--nopath` option is needed to ensure that you do not rename the preceeding directories first.

Comment: thanks. I moved one of them into a test folder to play with. All i get is 'find: ‘rename’: No such file or directory'

Comment: nothing changes...

Comment: ok....seems 'rename' is not just a basic command as I assumed and was not installed on the server haha...this seems to work now :)